# Parsing GSON Google Places API

Tags: java, json, gson, google-places-api

I'm trying to parse a json to my java object, but I'm getting error from gson.

The error is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "{   \"debug_info\" : [],   \"html_attributions\" : [],   \"results\" : [      {         \"geometry\" : {            \"location\" : {               \"lat\" : 53.330661,               \"lng\" : -6.265253            }         },         \"icon\" : \"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png\",         \"id\" : \"b50995ee5107706386c43d562fc614dc9db57937\",         \"name\" : \"Lower Deck\",         \"rating\" : 3.5,         \"reference\" : \"CnRoAAAATUQrAt8LAzje_32Uzm5jklTmhsYA_orKtp9DIO_-kmCTU7DsHkNBae3aY9dLusdqJaSGwdj6G_-LpqbKWIi5r0RjcJWHljxCex8wI9UMO93uqSpr63S6qyNjJdw01nGEl1LLtbtz4VRGuKdEAl6sShIQEeM3-QnEjeoO7lEWZBYQQBoU0TOKwurVvTs565wKYPLQNmkLF5w\",         \"types\" : [ \"bar\", \"establishment\" ],         \"vicinity\" : \"1 Portobello Harbour, Dublin\"      },      {         \"geometry\" : {            \"location\" : {               \"lat\" : 53.332361,               \"lng\" : -6.275473            }         },         \"icon\" : \"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png\",         \"id\" : \"8e8f338164d20d4ad7d943db980ce62d0325c2b5\",         \"name\" : \"The Headline Bar\",         \"rating\" : 3.6,         \"reference\" : \"CnRvAAAAvlARk-Q-08T9kuvY_mp90vn10jf84TDNKymDtVyEYvt1wg7TEJyaqGF_R6zDGkXBoKSOEfovqm-A8w42OlOa1yAE-nMdGVgR_EKJKu5HHdzUmKlkFoPqcJxbJpFAblqCMz_ClpbwMEMtFNLA_hZidRIQVCg4_6vqhJuSDSqtbIG2zxoUeEGHiUYqFk2e_aB18dqFSKx_E5Y\",         \"types\" : [ \"bar\", \"establishment\" ],         \"vicinity\" : \"118 S Circular Rd, Crumlin, Dublin\"      }   ],   \"status\" : \"OK\"}"
```

Then my classes are the following:

GoogleMapper

```
    @SerializedName("debug_info")
    private List<String> debug_info;

    @SerializedName("html_attributions")
    private List<String> html_attributions;

    @SerializedName("next_page_token")
    private String next_page_token;

    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<Results> results;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
```

Results

```
@SerializedName("geometry")
private Geometry geometry;

@SerializedName("icon")
private String icon;

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("photos")
private Photos photos;

@SerializedName("rating")
private Double rating;

@SerializedName("reference")
private String reference;

@SerializedName("types")
private List<String> types;

@SerializedName("vicinity")
private String vicinity;
```

Geometry

```
@SerializedName("location")
private Location location;
```

Location

```
@SerializedName("lat")
private Double lat;

@SerializedName("lng")
private Double lng;
```

Photos

```
    @SerializedName("height")
    private int height;

    @SerializedName("width")
    private int width;

    @SerializedName("html_attributions")
    private List<String> html_attributions;

    @SerializedName("photo_reference")
    private String photo_reference;
```

And finally, I'm trying to do the following code:

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(retorno.toString());

    GoogleMapper mapper = gson.fromJson(json, GoogleMapper.class);
```

Please, anyone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your Gson instance wrong. It should be

```
gson.toJson(ritorno);
```

you do **NOT** need to call `ritorno.toString()`

Gson can directly serialize from an object.

`toString()` has actually **nothing** to do with json, or serialization.

### Additional information about good practices:

You should implement your own toString() method for your classes to have better readability for debugging. It has nothing to do with serializing your object to a String.

Gson is extremely to use and if you are not worried about performances then it is a good choice. Otherwise there is (really) faster (but slightly less obvious to use or configure) libraries like : [Jackson-Json](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Comment: Hey man, thank you very much... the way that I was calling was wrong...

Instead of that, now I'm calling like this:

<code>Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
     GoogleMapper mapper = gson.fromJson(retorno.toString(), GoogleMapper.class);</code>

Comment: Why do you keep on calling the ritorno.toString() method?